# skype crashes after logging in

Tags: skype

In my 64 bit `Ubuntu 16.04.1` `skype` crashes (disappears) after logging in and no error message is displayed. Previously this problem was not present. What could be the reason?

Comment: Note: There is a reply by @NicholasOdicoh on the question this is marked as a duplicate of that explains how you can keep using Skype 4.3 by faking the version number.

Answer (score 11):

Evgeniy is indeed correct. I experienced the same problem on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, but it could be fixed by uninstalling the old Skype and installing a new one. To be precise, I did the following:

1.) Open Synaptic Package manager (I guess this also works with the Ubuntu Software Center) and type Skype in the search window. There were two packages installed. I marked both of them for complete removal.

2.) Go to www.skype.com and click on "Download Skype". The website proposes a .deb file, which I downloaded.

3.) Double-clicking on it opened the Ubuntu Software Center, where I hit the install button.

4.) Search for Skype in the Ubuntu-search window. Open it and log-in with the usual account settings.

As Fotis Skodras pointed out, Skype no longer works for 32bit systems. At home, where I have a 32bit Linux Mint, I've replaced Skype with Jitsi:
https://jitsi.org
It allows video conversation through the browser without installing anything. As there are shortcomings (e.g., one does not have a list of contacts), I was wondering if there are other free programs, with which Skype could be replaced on 32bit Linux systems?

Comment: Indeed this seems to have started happening after their (yet another) horrendous UI update the last few weeks, it needed a clean reinstall...

Answer (score 4):

I was using the older Skype v4.3 (which was supposed to be retired maybe 3 or 4 months ago) and yesterday I rebooted and it quits as soon as I try to login. I believe Microsoft has done this on purpose since they don't want anybody using the older versions, so it's not crashing, just getting a command to quit instantly. This is of course ridiculous and Microsoft shouldn't do that. Many are angry about the newer update, apparently history isn't searchable and chat logs are stored in the cloud! The database file isn't being updated. There is a heated discussion about it here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/end-of-life-of-skype-for-linux-43/70fe7036-ddf3-4fa3-9c06-1bca3ec0226c?auth=1

Comment: ```skype
echo $?
0``` -> app simply quits, no matter if your login creds are OK or not - their old login endpoint simply returns something which makes local binary to exit - this is a security risk IMHO... Goodbye Skype, I haven't used that shitware for a while...

Answer (score 0):

it works only if you have 64 bit linux :-(
Linux

Version

64-bit Ubuntu 14.04+
64-bit Debian 8.0+
64-bit OpenSUSE 13.3+
64-bit Fedora Linux 24+

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa10328/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-skype